# Instantiated objects with member functions, behave as not instantiated when passing their member function to a new thread

Tags: c++

I'm trying to parallelize array calculations, and for that purpose I've build a Shader (outer) class that has a Worker (inner) class. Outer class receives an array and it's size, then proceeds to divide it among new instances of Workers.
It creates a vector of workers, then a vector of threads that are assigned a worker function.
Unfortunately, the app crashed with a seg. fault and using a debugger I've confirmed that *some* objects aren't instantiated (while some actually are) and lack the required data.
Since instantiation was not done in parallel there should be no race conditions of any kind.

I'm using mingw_64 as a compiler. Additional libraries are `<iostream>,<c++/4.8.3/sstream>,<math.h>,<SDL.h>,<SDL_image.h>,<thread>,<vector>`.

Main function of Outer class:

```cpp
    void BlurShader::render()
    {
        int threadsNum;
        for (threadsNum = 6; threadsNum > 1; threadsNum--)
        {
            if (height % threadsNum == 0) break;
        }
        int heightStep = height / threadsNum;
        auto *workerObjects = new vector<Worker*>;
        auto *workerThreads = new vector<thread *>;

    // Instantiating workers:

        for (int i = 0; i < threadsNum; i++)
        {
            workerObjects->push_back(
        new Worker(this->original, this->palette, this->width, this->height,
            i * heightStep,((i + 1) * heightStep) - 1));
        }

        /* As you can see a lot of information is streamed into the worker,     
           and it is relying on it. Then in a second for loop I create 
           threads: */

        for (int i = 0; i < threadsNum; i++)
        {
            workerThreads->push_back(new thread([&]() 
            {
                (*workerObjects)[i]->threadProcess(); 
            }));
        }

        // Then the main thread waits for threads to finish:
        for (int j = 0; j < threadsNum; j++)
        {
            (*workerThreads)[j]->join();
            delete (*workerThreads)[j];
        }
        // Cleanup

        for(int i=0;i<threadsNum;i++)
        {
            delete (*workerObjects)[i];
        }
        delete workerObjects;
        delete workerThreads;
        memcpy(original, palette, height * width * size);
    }
```

Looking forward for your advice.
If you find that I've used threads incorrectly, I'll gladly listen. I'm only one week into c++ so anything goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with the way lambda captures `i`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < threadsNum; i++)
        {
            workerThreads->push_back(new thread([&]() // [1]
            {
                (*workerObjects)[i]->threadProcess(); 
            }));
        }
```

`i` is captured by reference, but you don't know when the body of thread i.e. closure is called, so probably `i` was modified (by *for* loop) before the correct value of `i` was read.

Pass `i` by copy:

```
for (int i = 0; i < threadsNum; i++)
        {
            workerThreads->push_back(new thread([&,i]() // pass i by copy 
            {
                (*workerObjects)[i]->threadProcess(); 
            }));
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
Could you recommend a good tutorial for advanced c++? Lambdas, captures, advanced multi-threading, etc.

Comment: Have a look at [about c++](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info) many links (for example *C++ Core Guidelines*) and one of them contains the list of c++ books.